# Folder Color option is not available

Tags: nautilus, directory

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and downloaded Folder Color as described in ["How to change folders color?"](/questions/134997/how-to-change-folders-color).

[image]

But though I restarted my pc again the option is not available when I right click on any folder.

[image]

What can I do now?

[image]

Note: The answer I accepted is because it worked, I had already installed the Folder Color software and was using it for a long time but it stopped working one day so this question is regarding what to do if the Folder Color is not working if Installed already.Still, if you consider it duplicate of any XYZ question please think again.

Comment: Is it working with the last release? If not, which icon theme are you using? Best regards

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg -l folder-color nautilus` and `nautilus --version`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I added the details you asked, kindly help if you can ..now.

Comment: Thanks. Again, could you please post textual information as text and not as images? See my first comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate “[How to change folders color?](/q/134997/175814)” as the accepted answers are identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run these commands

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:costales/folder-color
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install folder-color
 nautilus -q
```

Comment: Although these commands may work to solve OP's problem you should elaborate on what they do and how they solve the problem.

Comment: But that's exactly the same as accepted answer to the question linked in this question. It should have worked the first time (barring intermittent networking issues).

Comment: I put the answer up before somebody added the link.  However you are correct.@DavidFoerster