# My right click is not working in 16.04

Tags: lenovo

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 for the past two days.My right click  is not working properly in touch pad.it is working fine with external mouse.Please anyone help me with this issues.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this if an answer here will help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/932021/folder-color-option-is-not-available.